# Opacity of div container with background-color style

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a fix colorstring like "#ff0000" and I set this fix string like this (with AngularJS):

```
<div style="background-color: {{chatMessageOfUser.color}};">...
```

Now I will set an opacity only to the `background-color`. Actually I dont know how to do this without splitting the `chatMessageOfUser.color`- string?

Comment: you could create a filter translating the color value to `rgba(r, g, b, a)`

Comment: see the example of [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: what is the input format of `chatMessageOfUser.color`?

Comment: Why not just do `style="background-color: {{chatMessageOfUser.color}}; opacity:0.5;"` ?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
ng-class="{'opacityclass': chatMessageOfUser.color == '#ff0000'}"
```

**CSS**

```
.opacityclass
{
opacity :0.5
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.opacityclass
{
opacity :0.5
}
</style>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-style="myObj">Welcome</h1>
<h1 ng-class="{'opacityclass': chatMessageOfUser.color == '#ff0000'}">Welcome</h1>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td ng-class="{'opacityclass': x.color == '#ff0000'}">{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {  

$scope.names = [
{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany" , "color":"#00000"},
{"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"fdgdgdg" ,"color":"#066000"},
{"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"yuiyui" ,"color":"#ff0000"}
]
$scope.chatMessageOfUser ={
  "color" : "#ff0000",
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

reference https://plnkr.co/edit/v6hbk1uMzS5p8bxcDLFT?p=preview

Comment: happy coding @Fiido93

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you will need to split your input. You can do this in a filter however.

Here is some rough example (note that this is not production ready since you still need input validation, ...):

```
.filter('color', function()
{
    return function(colorString, opacity)
  {
    opacity = opacity || 1;

    colorString = colorString.replace('#', '');

    var splitColor = colorString.match(/.{1,2}/g);

    splitColor = splitColor.map(function(hex) { return parseInt(hex, 16); });

    return 'rgba(' + splitColor[0] + ', ' + splitColor[1] + ', ' + splitColor[2] + ', ' + opacity + ')';
  }
});
```

The usage of this snippet would be

```
<div class="colorField" style="background-color: {{colorInput | color:colorAlpha}}">
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/aa86u410/) to see it in action.